# Concyclic Points on Hyperbola

Tags: conic-sections

If $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, and $\delta$ are the eccentric angles of four concyclic points on a hyperbola, then prove that their sum is an even multiple of $\pi$.

I tried doing this by writing a general second degree equation that will certainly pass through these four points using the equation of the hyperbola as $x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 = 1$ and two chords that pass through these two points each, but the condition is a bit too lengthy. Any advice on simplifying it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a figure ?

Comment: Not so good at LaTeX so..... I'm sorry but no figure here ☹️

Comment: related : https://www.toppr.com/content/concept/concyclic-points-207106/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

WLOG the equation of the circle $$x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$$

Now the four points be $P(a\sec t, b\tan t)$ where $t\in\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$

$$a^2\sec^2t+b^2\tan^2t+2g(a\sec t)+2f(b\tan t)+c=0$$

$$\iff a^2+b^2\sin^2t+2ga\cos t+2fb\sin t\cos t+c\cos^2t=0$$

Now use  [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution)  to form a quadratic equation in $\tan\dfrac t2$

Now use [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) to find $$\tan\dfrac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta}2=\dfrac{\sum\tan\dfrac\alpha2-\sum_{\text{cyc}}\tan\dfrac\alpha2\tan\dfrac\beta2\tan\dfrac\gamma2}{\cdots}=0$$

Comment: [+1] By chance, I found **your** solution to the analogous result where the hyperbola is replaced by an ellipse (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/623242). It means that there must be a more general solution, using maybe homographies and/or pencils of conics...

Comment: @JeanMarie, Thanks  for reminding that solution and linking to this

Comment: An interesting connected issue/solution : (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2904889)

Comment: Yes this is usually the case with these two as they are both 'central' conics...