# Condition for 4 points on a hyperbola to be concyclic

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I found a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3577217/concyclic-points-on-hyperbola) claiming that if $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\theta$ are the eccentric angles of points $X,Y,Z,T$ we can parameterize those points on the hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ as $(a\sec(t),b\tan(t))$ which makes sense. Further in the post is proven that if the four points are concyclic we have $\tan(\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\theta}{2})=0$. My question is whether this works backwards. I checked on desmos and almost never points with eccentric angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma, -\alpha-\beta-\gamma$ are concyclic. Can someone provide a reason for this.

Comment: The post that you referenced is talking about an ellipse, not a hyperbola ???

Comment: The same holds for hyperbolahttps://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3577217/concyclic-points-on-hyperbola

Comment: In classical mathematical terms : "works backwards" = "reciprocal proposition is true".

Comment: @JeanMarie I am asking whether there is a not so ugly if and only if condition for four points to be concyclic.

Comment: I've written a small code, intersecting the hyperbola $\dfrac{x^2}{9} - \dfrac{y^2}{4} = 1 $ with the circle $ (x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 = 25 $, and calculated the eccentric angles of the points of intersection, and as it turns out, the condition $\tan \left( \dfrac{\alpha + \beta+ \gamma + \delta }{2} \right) = 0 $ does not hold.

Comment: However,  the condition $\tan \left( \dfrac{\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta}{2} \right) = 0 $ does indeed hold for intersection between an ellipse and a circle.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you very much